# Dynamic ImageView in list item android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am developing a twitter based app and showing tweets as an item in recycler view. I have an imageview in the item layout, which is shown only if a tweet also have an image associated with it. I'm doing this by setting imageview visibility as GONE in xml and if a image url is present, I set the imageview visibility to VISIBLE in onBindView.

I want the imageview height to be dynamic, so I set its height to wrap content. But when the list is shown, it looks like the images appear out of nowhere and on scrolling some othe issues appear like when the scrolling speed is fast then the imageview is showing some other image which is replaced the correct image after some time and this change is quite noticeable. So, right now I'm using a fixed height on my imageview which scale down the image, in short not filling the imageview. The problem with this, is that if image height is less than specified height in xml, then a lot of whitespace above and below the imageview appears .I want the image appearing in the list item to be as big as possible without any issues mentioned. How can I do that.

Also, I'm using glide to load my images.

As requested here is my code:

**item_layout**

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_tweet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:textColorLink="@color/primary"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_tweet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MyAdapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
    holder.tweetTextView.setText(tweet.descripion);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tweet.tweetImage)) {
        holder.tweetImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(tweet.imagUrl)
                .crossFade()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.tweetImageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code? you can create a custom object for your adapter with 2 strings: item name and image name. when you populate your reciclerview you can add any image nd text, but we need to see your code

Comment: instead of setting wrapcontent to your image view... just set a minimum height say 10dp & then set its height dynamically as the image is received from your backend server

Answer (score 0):

CenterCrop() will remove spaces above and below. Without a fixed height for the imageView, convertView will return its previous layout height which will probably be different than the new size needed and therefore cause "jumping effects" (layout changes) when scrolling after image is loaded if wrap_content is used